# X does not name a type in c++

Tags: c++, class

I am learning c++, in particular, I am learning about inheritance. I wrote the following code where I wanted to print the contents of `protected_stuff`, a variable defined within the `protected` access specifier in the `MainClass`.

Here is my code:

- inheritance.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"MainClass.h"
#include"DerivedClass.h"


int main(){

    DerivedClass a;
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

- DerivedClass.h

```
#ifndef DERIVEDCLASS

#define DERIVEDCLASS

class DerivedClass: public MainClass{
private:
    int val;
protected:
    int val2;
public:
    int val3;

    void func(void){
        std::cout<<protected_stuff;
    }

};

#endif
```

- MainClass.h

```
#ifndef MAINCLASS
#define MAINCLASS


class MainClass{

private:
    int value;
    char charecter;

    value= 10;
    charecter='a';

protected:
    int protected_stuff;
    protected_stuff = 2;


public:
    int public_stuff;
    public_stuff = 3;

};

#endif
```

When I try to run `g++ -I . inheritance.cpp` I get the following errors:

```
In file included from inheritance.cpp:2:
MainClass.h:11:2: error: 'value' does not name a type
   11 |  value= 10;
      |  ^~~~~
MainClass.h:12:2: error: 'charecter' does not name a type
   12 |  charecter='a';
      |  ^~~~~~~~~
MainClass.h:16:2: error: 'protected_stuff' does not name a type
   16 |  protected_stuff = 2;
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MainClass.h:21:2: error: 'public_stuff' does not name a type
   21 |  public_stuff = 3;
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Later I modified `MainClass.h` and the code works fine.

```
#ifndef MAINCLASS
#define MAINCLASS


class MainClass{

private:
    int value= 10;
    char charecter='a';

    // value= 10;
    // charecter='a';

protected:
    int protected_stuff= 2;
    // protected_stuff = 2;


public:
    int public_stuff = 3;
    // public_stuff = 3;

};

#endif
```

My question is *what was I doing wrong*? I tried looking at various other questions on SO but couldn't find something similar:

- [error: 'x' does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470822/error-x-does-not-name-a-type)
- [error: ‘X’ does not name a type X in template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352347/error-x-does-not-name-a-type-x-in-template-functions)
- ["X does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/x-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c)
- ["Y does not name a type" error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/y-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c)
- [Error C++ : does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335341/error-c-does-not-name-a-type)
- [Another "x" does not name a type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882505/another-x-does-not-name-a-type-error)
- [Correct place to initialize class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722822/correct-place-to-initialize-class-variables)
- [Initialisation and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment)

Comment: You can't have code (for example assignments like `value= 10;`) outside of functions. Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335341/error-c-does-not-name-a-type and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938810/y-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c

Comment: I should have properly read **"Y does not name a type" error in C++**... Please close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The one you linked "Correct place to initialize class variables?" is fundamentally the same problem: both you and that OP are trying to treat an *instance* variable as if it belonged to the class. Note that in some *other* languages (e.g. Python), analogous code *would* create something that belongs to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors have nothing to do with inheritance. The same code would be an error without any inheritance.

In C++ statements like `value = 10;` must be placed inside functions or constructors. So this is OK (statement inside a constructor)

```
class MainClass{
    int value= 10;
    MainClass()
    {
        value = 10;
    }
};
```

so is this (statement inside a function)

```
class MainClass{
    int value= 10;
    void function()
    {
        value = 10;
    }
};
```

On the other hand `int value = 10;` is a declaration so it can go outside of a function.

This is very basic C++ syntax and semantics. You need to understand the difference between a statement and a declaration. It suggests to me that you need to spend some more time learning the basics of C++ before you tackle inheritance.